# Pandoc: Create html file without specifying a filename

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, pandoc

In my company, we're trying to transition from writing in Word to using markdown. We need several output formats for markdown, so I'm trying to create a grunt.js task that can watch a folder, and convert markdown files into the desired outputs.
Required outputs are: DOCX, PDF, and HTML.

I'm using the node-pandoc plugin for grunt.js to handle the conversions.

I've currently got the grunt task creating the docx and pdf. The issue is the HTML file - Pandoc seems to require that an HTML filename be specified explicitly, instead of just using the name of the original file. If none are specified, it generates an error (openBinaryFile: does not exist).

My current task options look like this:

```
    grunt.initConfig({
        node_pandoc: {

          engdocx: {
                  //English source+options
              expand: true,
              src: 'Eng/*.md',
              dest: 'pdfBuild/',
              ext: '.docx',
              flatten: true,
              options: {
                flags: '-f markdown -t docx -o --reference-doc=reference.docx --metadata-file=EngMeta.yml'
              }
            },
         hebdocx:{
                //Hebrew source+options
            expand: true,
            src: 'Heb/*.md',
            dest: 'pdfBuild/',
            ext: '.docx',
            flatten: true,
            options: {
              flags: '-f markdown -t docx -o --reference-doc=reference.docx --metadata-file=HebMeta.yml'
            },
            // Target-specific file lists and/or options go here.
          },
          html_heb: {
              // Convert markdown to html
              expand: true,
              src: ['Heb/*.md'],
              dest: 'Final/',
              ext: '.html',
              flatten: true,
              options: {
                flags: '-f markdown -t html -o'
              }, 
          },
          html_eng: {
            // Convert markdown to html
            expand: true,
            src: ['Eng/*.md'],
            dest: 'Final/',
            ext: '.html',
            flatten: true,
            options: {
              flags: '-f markdown -t html -s -o ' 
            }, 
        }
```

I'm wondering if I can:

1. Extract the filename from within the task.
2. Append it dynamically to the options for each task so pandoc knows what the desired file name is.

Alternatively, if I can persuade pandoc to generate the files without specifying the file name explicitly.

Comment: `pandoc -t html -o outfile`, see https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing a -s for standalone flag.

```
          html_heb: {
              // Convert markdown to html
              expand: true,
              src: ['Heb/*.md'],
              dest: 'Final/',
              ext: '.html',
              flatten: true,
              options: {
                flags: '-f markdown -t html -o -s' // Was missing a -s.
              },
```